# Getting local businesses to install bicycle parking

Tags: advocacy

I live in the far southern community of Nashville, Tn. If any of you know Nashville, it is very late to the bicycling movement. They have some good efforts currently but they are focused in the high rent downtown areas and super cool East-Nashville.

The fact is cycling is much better where I live but there are a lot of older people who would not think of cycling the half mile to the store. 
 I have this idea that if we could get all the retail and mall owners to switch out the parking benches for smokers to bicycle parking, it might make the prospect of cycling more inviting.
Anyone have the experience int heir community where bicycle parking was soundly embraced? 
How did you do it?

Comment: Why start from scratch? There are probably bike advocacy groups in your area. Find them and get involved.

Comment: YEs and that is a great idea and I attempted this last year. The point I mentioned about investment being concentrated in East Nashville and downtown is a function of ease of execution and a younger market that may present more immediate traction.

Comment: Maybe the local bike groups just don't have enough volunteers so they have to focus their efforts on areas that will be more bike friendly. Maybe you could be the one to take on south Nashville.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bicycle parking is a convenience but it is never a factor in my decision on if a ride my bike.  Worse case I lock my bike to the smoking bench.  At my gym I have a secure bike room so I will ride my nice bike.  But if I did not have the room I would still ride my beater.

Now a good bike route is a factor.  If you want to encourage biking then work with the city on bike routes/lanes.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to update contributors and thank you for the input. 
The biggest grocer stores, namely Publix and Kroger has Media Relations staff that gobbled up the idea. 
 Bike parking is low investment and has a big payback in PR!
It helped ripping this image from the latest NACTO Bicycle Design Guide and emailing it with my communications (email, phone call followed with a letter) and copying my councilwoman for endorsement.
[image: NACTO Bike Corral image]

Answer (score 1):

You might consider sharing bike parking information from other cities of similar sizes.  Here's one to check http://www.portlandoregon.gov/transportation/article/99190  Maybe showing them something would help.
Another idea is to contact bike advocacy groups in nearby towns and ask them their strategies.